# Check What Same Text Is Found In A List & List The Text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have 2 columns of values. I want to create a formula that looks at Column A and finds what Column B text values are within in the Column A items. Then I want what matches to list in column C. I've posted an example below.

| Column A Apples List | Column B Categories | Column C Results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gala Apples | Gala | Gala |
| Pink Lady and Honeycrisp Apples | Fuji | Honeycrisp |
| Fuji and Honeycrisp Apples | Honeycrisp | Fuji, Honeycrisp |
| Gala and Honeycrisp Apples | Golden Delicious | Gala, Honeycrisp |
| Green Apples |  |  |
| Golden Delicious and Fuji |  | Fuji, Golden Delicious |

I've tried the following but this does not work and shows no matches.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A2=$B$2:$B$4,$B$2:$B$4,"no matches"))
```

Comment: This is challenging because you haven't really explained your logic. Why even bother with Column B?  `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," Apples","")," and",",")`

Comment: Hi @BlindSpots apologies, I added one more row to help illustrate; this one has a value that doesn't have a corresponding category that needs to be flagged.

Comment: Np.  Still don't see it flagged in your sample table.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(IF(COUNTIF(B2:B,SPLIT(A2:A," ")),SPLIT(A2:A," "),),LAMBDA(ζ,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,ζ))))
```

#### Update

```
=LAMBDA(list,categories,MAP(list,LAMBDA(_list,
TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFNA(FILTER(categories,REGEXMATCH(_list,"(?i)\b"&categories&"\b")))))))
(A2:INDEX(A2:A,MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))),B2:INDEX(B2:B,MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))
```

Comment: Hi @ztiaa, this works great except it's running into issues with Column B values that have a space. I just added another row to share an example (e.g. "Golden Delicious"). In other words, if a category has two words it doesn't add it to Column C even if Column A has that value . I hope this makes sense. 

What would I need to adjust? Can you explain your formula to me?

Comment: See updated formula.

Comment: Please add a brief description of the features used and explanation of why this answer is correct. (note: this was flagged as low quality and has one delete vote)